# Remove evens from a list with del function

Tags: python, list, for-loop, del

I'm not allowed to use the .remove() function to delete even numbers in a list and the specs say: You will be modifying  the original list, so its id() must not change.This is what I have:

```
def remove_evens(xs):
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        for x in xs:
            if x%2==0:
                del xs[i]
    return xs
```

If for instance I test the function and I input xs=[1,2,3,4,5] it returns [3,5]. I don't know why the 1 doesn't return

Comment: Are you required to remove items from the existing list, or can you build a new list of the items which you'd like to keep?

Comment: Bad Idea to change a list *while* you're iterating over it.  Quick fix is to iterate over a copy of the list:  `for x in xs[:]:`.

Comment: Look up built-in function `reversed` and iterate backwards while deleting.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX the specs say: . You will be modifying 
the original list, so its id() must not change.

Comment: @user2829177: Please update your question to include this vital information then!

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're iterating over the list and modifying it at the same time. This means the index `i` isn't always correct because you've just removed an element from the list. This leads to skipping elements and that's why the `1` isn't in there.

You can do:

```
def remove_evens(xs):
    return [x for x in xs if x % 2 != 0]
```

This uses a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to create a list without the even numbers. If you need to modify the existing list you can do:

```
def remove_evens(xs):
    to_remove = []
    for i, x in enumerate(xs):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            to_remove.append(i)
    for j in to_remove:
        del xs[j]
    return xs
```

This creates a list `to_remove` which keeps track of the positions of the elements that need to be removed.

Comment: You clearly did not read the question. The OP cannot use .remove(), and the id() of the list must stay the same.

Comment: The requirement that the `id()` must not change was not available until after I posted my answer. I now updated my code to use `del`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this will work for you.

```
>>> xs = [1,5,123,6,2,34]
>>> id(xs)
35519496L
>>> lastidx = len(xs) - 1
>>> for i, x in enumerate(reversed(xs)):
...     if x%2==0:
...         del xs[lastidx-i]
...
>>> xs
[1, 5, 123]
>>> id(xs)
35519496L
```

It's linear time because it iterates over the list only once. When you iterate over a list backwards, you can freely delete elements without modifying the indexes of future elements that you haven't looped over yet. Also the id of the list does not change with this method, as you can see. :)

Here is another way to do the same thing with only `range`/`xrange` and `len`.

```
>>> xs = [1,5,123,6,2,34]
>>> for i in range(len(xs)-1,-1,-1):
...     if xs[i]%2==0:
...         del xs[i]
...
>>> xs
[1, 5, 123]
```

Both ways do the same thing so whichever way you decide to use is a matter of preference/personal style.

Comment: Based on the OP's requirements to remove items from the same list he's iterating over, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! @VooDooNOFX and Shashank Gupta. This worked for me. I actually tried using this method but I didn't have range(len(xs)-1,-1,-1)

Comment: There are two ways you can call range, one is `range(stop)` and the other is `range(start, stop[, step])` where square brackets denote an optional argument. You can find all the information on this (and other useful built-in functions) in [the library documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

It’s a bad idea to delete items from a list as you are iterating over the list.

Here’s a few ways in which you can achieve your goal:

```
>>> def deleteEvens(L):
...   dels = []
...   for i,x in enumerate(L):
...     if not x%2:
...       dels.append(i)
...   for d in dels[::-1]:
...     L.pop(d)
... 
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> deleteEvens(L)
>>> L
[1, 3, 5]
```

OR

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> odds = [i for i in L if i%2]
>>> odds
[1, 3, 5]
```

OR

```
>>> def delEvens(L):
...   dels = []
...   for i,x in enumerate(L):
...     if not x%2:
...       dels.append(i)
...   for d in dels[::-1]:
...     del L[d]
... 
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> delEvens(L)
>>> L
[1, 3, 5]
```